# SQL - Select date ranges without overlapping

Tags: sql, select, plsql, overlap

I have the following table (Oracle database):

| ID | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.22 | 28.02.22 |
| 1 | 01.03.22 | 30.06.22 |
| 1 | 01.07.22 | 31.12.22 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 | null |
| 2 | 01.01.22 | 31.03.22 |
| 2 | 01.04.22 | null |

How do I best extract now all date ranges without overlaps over both IDs? The final result set should look like:

| valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.22 | 28.02.22 |
| 01.03.22 | 31.03.22 |
| 01.04.22 | 30.06.22 |
| 01.07.23 | 31.12.22 |
| 01.01.23 | null |

Null stands for max_date (PL / SQL Oracle Max Date).

Moreover, I should only select the values valid for the current year (let's assume we are already in 2022).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I would start with a query that extracts the overlapping ranges (which might be done by a simple join).

Comment: Why is the line from 01.03.22 not valid to 30.06.22 (second line in your example) ?   Some rules that your are applying to select these dates are missing?  What is the meaning of `id` in relation to the final list of date ranges?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply next select statement:

```
with 
  -- main table
  t1 AS (SELECT w, q1, q2, to_date(q1,'dd.mm.yy') q1d, to_date(q2,'dd.mm.yy') q2d FROM www)

  -- custom year in YYYY format
, t0 AS (SELECT '2022' y FROM dual)

  -- join and order dates FROM - TO
, t2 AS (SELECT t1.q1, t1.q1d, s2.q2, s2.q2d 
         FROM t1 
         LEFT JOIN t1 s2 on t1.q1d <= s2.q2d 
         ORDER BY t1.q1d,  s2.q2d)

  -- mark the first each new row-pair by row_number()
 , t3 AS (SELECT t2.*, 
                 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.q1d ORDER BY t2.q1d ) r 
          FROM t2 )
 
-- join custom year value and select desired rows based on that value
SELECT q1, q2 FROM t3 
  JOIN t0 on 1=1
WHERE r = 1 
  -- for the custom year
     AND t0.y <= to_char(q1d, 'yyyy')
ORDER BY q1d;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33095b/1)

In my table-example dates are presented in `varchar2` datatype and in `dd.mm.yy` date format. In case if your table fields have datatype `date`, then you don't need to implement function `to_date()` for those 2 fields.

Used table sample:

```
create table www (w integer, q1 varchar2(30), q2 varchar2(30));
    
insert into www values (1, '01.01.22', '28.02.22');
insert into www values (1, '01.03.22', '30.06.22');
insert into www values (1, '01.07.22', '31.12.22');
insert into www values (1, '01.01.23', '');
insert into www values (2, '01.01.22', '31.03.22');
insert into www values (2, '01.04.22', '');
```

---

**If** your table sample has more rows which are have `null` value in the field `valid_to` and the dates in `valid_from` are not in any range, let's say:

```
insert into www values (1, '01.01.24', '');
```

then previous solution will produce more rows in the end with `null` value.
In this case you can use that more complex solution:

```
... 
-- join custom year value and select desired rows based on that value
  , t4 as (SELECT q1, q2, q1d FROM t3 
            JOIN t0 on 1=1 
           WHERE  r = 1 AND
            -- for the custom year
                t0.y <= to_char(q1d, 'yyyy')
           ORDER BY q1d)

  -- filter non-nullable rows 
 , t5 as ( SELECT q1, q2 FROM t4 WHERE Q2 IS NOT NULL )

  -- max date from rows where Q2 field has null value 
 , t6 as ( SELECT to_char(MAX(Q1D),'dd.mm.yy') q1, q2 
           FROM t4 
           WHERE Q2 IS NULL 
           GROUP BY q2) 

 -- append rows with max date  
 SELECT * FROM t5
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM t6;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9ee0/1)